# Reflection returns com.sun.star.uno.XInterface type for all objects

Tags: javascript, libreoffice, uno-automation-bridge

The `getType` method is supposed to return an object which represents the type of the item passed into the method:

```
var serviceManager = new ActiveXObject('com.sun.star.ServiceManager');
var desktop = serviceManager.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop");
var document = desktop.loadComponentFromURL("private:factory/swriter", "_blank", 0, []);
var coreReflection = serviceManager.createInstance("com.sun.star.reflection.CoreReflection");

// should return a type representing the com.sun.star.frame.Desktop type
var classInfo = coreReflection.getType(desktop);
```

However, the `classInfo` always seems to contain the `com.sun.star.uno.XInterface` type:

```
// outputs com.sun.star.uno.XInterface
WScript.Echo(classInfo.getName());
```

Even if I pass in other objects, the output is the same:

```
classInfo = coreReflection.getType(document);
WScript.Echo(classInfo.getName());
```

**How can I find out the actual type?**

(Originally posted at [ask.libreoffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/127845/reflection-always-returns-typename-as-comsunstarunoxinterface/))

Comment: These questions are most likely best asked at the LibreOffice developer mailing lists. Most likely the only person who can answer such questions and give advice on how to implement a good uno bridge is Stephan Bergmann who is a paid LibreOffice developer.

Comment: @moggi I'm not (yet) interested in implementing a uno bridge; I am interested in using [the existing Automation bridge](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Bridge/Automation_Bridge); but many thanks anyway.

Comment: even in that case Stephan and the mailing list might be the best approach. E.g. com.sun.star.frame.Desktop is a service and not a type but only Stephan or possibly Michael would know the details why getType returns XInterface instead of one of the other interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the "implementation name" rather than the "interface type name."

The following code adapted from [XrayTool](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Extensions_development_basic#Xray_tool) results in  the message `com.sun.star.comp.framework.Desktop`  (`comp` here can [perhaps be ignored](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=11872#p55682)).

```
WScript.Echo(desktop.ImplementationName)
```

There is also a good approach which however is available only for Basic.

```vb
obj = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop")
MsgBox obj.DBG_Properties
```

This will produce a long message, starting out with `Properties of object 
"com.sun.star.frame.Desktop"`.

Finally, don't forget about [supportsService](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/UNO_Tools#The_supportsService_Method), although it may not be as relevant for your particular use case.  When writing macros, the preferred way is to check whether a particular object supports a service rather than checking what type the object actually is.